# Optimal time for auxiliary rocket engine ignition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, rocket-science

> A Rocket intends to leave the Earth's gravitational field. The fuel in the rocket's main engine is a little less than the total fuel required, and thus an auxiliary engine, only functional for a short amount of time has to be used.
>   We need to find out when is the best time to switch on the auxiliary engine:
>   a. During take off
>   b. Just before the main engine fuel runs out
>   c. Any time will have the same effect

My thinking was that engines basically generate power (work). Now a given amount of work will result in maximum displacement when the field it works against is weakest - i.e. when the rocket is furthest away from the Earth and hence it'd be best that the auxiliary engine must be used just before the main engine fuel runs out.

However the answer is during take off. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please consider writing more useful question titles, see [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would be looking at changes in velocity rather than changes in position.

Comment: -1 Insufficient information. Can both engines be used together? Does the auxilliary engine provide the same thrust as the main engine?

Comment: Related : ["Suicide Burn" rocket problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191031)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the total power versus gravity. For example if you switched on only the auxiliary engine, perhaps the rocket does not lift off at all, yet you still burn through the auxiliary fuel. The faster you can get away from the surface, the better, as your advantage increases with height; so the earlier you engage all possible engines, the better.

In fact, the ideal fuel usage (provided the payload is study enough) is to launch from a cannon, with all the fuel used at once. The main reasons we don't do that are that a) air resistance fouls up the plan, as it is higher near the surface and increases rapidly with velocity and b) it would kill all the astronauts and break all the equipment.

Comment: *your advantage increases with height* What advantage?

Comment: @sammygerbil The advantage of your rockets' push over Earth's pull. Imagine if you had a rocket engine that provided 10m/s^2 acceleration to your rocket; at the surface this is barely more than the gravitational acceleration (9.8m/s^2). Your rocket would lift off slowly. As the rocket climbs the gravity weakens so at a certain height, the gravitational acceleration is, say, 5m/s^2 so you can make the same ∆v with less fuel.